# Cannot add a ban reason to my discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

hi i have this ban command and i want to be able to specify a reason but i can't figure out how to do it? nothing i have tried has worked, so any help would be appreciated

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("!ban")) {
        if(message.member.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS")){
            const member = message.mentions.members.first();
            if (member){
                member.ban().then((member) => {
                    message.channel.send(":anger: " + member.displayName + " has been successfully banned. ");
                }).catch(() => {
                    message.channel.send(":exclamation: Oops! Please try again.");
                })
            } else {
                message.channel.send(':exclamation: Please enter a user in the server and try again.');
            }
        } else {
            message.channel.send(':no_entry_sign: You do not have permission.');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
GuildMember.ban({reason: "This is the reason."})
```

Comment: so that worked (thanks) but how would i make it so the user gets to input the ban reason, e.g `!ban @InDisguise very rude`

Comment: Check [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html).